# Polyhedron volume formula

Tags: calculus

Where doese the prefactor 1/3 for the choice of vector field F→=x→3 in the polyhedron volume formula ∫∇⋅F→dV=∮F→⋅n^dS=V=∑ki=1xi→⋅ni^Ai3 come from?

Comment: The formulae in your question are mangled. Can you correct them? If you know $\LaTeX$, you can use it to write math here.

Comment: @user58339 If you are the OP (original poster) then request for merging your two accounts (by flagging for moderator attention)

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer,  I think that may be an invitation to fraud and vandalism. If  the OP has two accounts then he must use the first one to edit his own question, under which he opened this thread, or write another question altogether with the new account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prefactor in Polyhedron volume formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279195/prefactor-in-polyhedron-volume-formula)