# Prefactor in Polyhedron volume formula

Tags: calculus

Where doese the prefactor $\frac{1}{3}$ for the choice of vector field $F=\frac{x}{3}$ in the polyhedron volume formula $\int \nabla \cdot F dV = \int F\cdot n dA  = \sum \frac{1}{3}x_i⋅n_i\cdot A_i$  come from?

The wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume mentions that the divergence of the vector field $F=\frac{x}{3}$ is equal to 1, which is not the case.

So where does the $\frac{1}{3}$ come from?

Comment: The divergence of $F(x) = x/3$ is $1$. What do you think it is?

Comment: I do not see it.

$\nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{3}$ or is it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence of $\mathbf F(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x/3 = (x_1/3,x_2/3,x_3/3)$ is
$$\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\mathbf F(\mathbf x) &= \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x_3} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\frac{x_1}3\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(\frac{x_2}3\right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\left(\frac{x_3}3\right) \\
&= \frac13 + \frac13 + \frac13 \\
&= 1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahhh, So it is $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

Alright, I thought that $F$ is chosen such that $F  = (\frac{1}{3} \cdot x, 0, 0)$.

The initial thought was that $\nabla\cdot F = 1$, if $F=(x,0,0)$.

Thank you, know it is clear.